Returning most current feature in clip area using FME
I'm trying to update an AGOL layer using FME and some FGDBs. I currently have multiple File Geodatabases, each representing a survey completed over the last 30 years, and an ArcGIS Online layer that has some of these surveys uploaded but is missing most.
I've created a script that compares the FGDBs to the AGOL layer and looks for overlaps using a Clipper. Where overlaps are found the features inside the overlap are added to an AGOL Archive layer and the features outside of the overlap are added to the current AGOL layer.
However, the current FME model does not check what the newest input is. It just assumes that the AGOL layer is the most up-to-date info and sends the FGDB layers to the archive where an overlap is found. This is not always correct as sometimes the FGDB data is the most current.
I want to update the FME model to merge the overlapping FGDB and AGOL layers, check which has the higher Year field, and then add the most up-to-date feature to the AGOL Current layer and remove the overlapping data from the AGOL layer (see rough model below).

I'm relatively new to FME so I'm not sure how to compare the merged feature to filter out the values with the most recent Year or how to delete only the overlapping features from the Current AGOL Layer.
Which tool do I use to filter the overlapping records and how do I do the delete so that only the overlapping records are removed?

Please look into the Change Detector transformer https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-Transformers/Transformers/changedetector.htm you can use this for changes in geometry or attributes or both.

There is a good official video here on the Change Detector https://engage.safe.com/webinars/managing-changing-data-with-fme/

Is this comparing areas to areas? I think I used an AreaOnAreaOverlayer, create lists, then sort list on year, keep the newest year, archive the rest.

@nielsgerrits. Yep, it's comparing areas to areas. I'll check that tool out
